# Can't add foreign key to mySQL table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE user_role (
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
);
```

This returns "*#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint*"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent type and the child type are exactly the same.  You cannot have one as Integer and another as Small Integer or Float.  The user_id and role_id in both tables must have the identical type.